# Package *package...* does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]

Якобы не существует проект, хотя при просмотре через проводник этот пакет с файлами есть. Я также могу через Ctrl зайти в этот пакет, то есть он однозначно существует.[image]
[image][image]

Comment: А покажите сразу build.gradle, все равно без этого не обойдется

Comment: И покажите структуру файлов проекта. В выпадающем списке слева вверху над списком файлов выберите `project`

Comment: Я ничего со вчерашнего дня не менял, но сегодня все скомпилировалось без проблем

Comment: @Dmitry, тогда это может быть просто глюк Android Studio. Или чёрная магия)